# UUID returns nil

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to get the Unique identifier, But I always get a nil value.

```
static NSString* UUID_KEY = @"CDVUUID"
NSString* app_uuid = [userDefaults stringForKey:UUID_KEY];
NSLog(@"udd:%@",app_uuid);
```

Comment: You are getting it from userdefaults but have you ever stored it there?

Comment: Did you save anything with key "CDVUUID"? userDefaults dont generate UUIDS, so you are asking how create an UUID?

Answer (score 1):

You are just getting it from Userdefaults which is only used to save info and retrieving it. It will not generate your UUID. So if you have never saved it with key "**CDVUUID**" in the past, your code will always give nil as there is no value saved in userdefaults for key **CDVUUID**

To generate UUID -

```
NSString* app_uuid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

or

```
NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

You can then save it in Userdefaults and then retrieve it at a later stage when you need it from userdefaults.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you copied this code from [CDVDevice.m](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/src/ios/CDVDevice.m) but you only copied part of it.

The entire function, which creates and saves a UUID if one doesn't exist, is:

```
- (NSString*)uniqueAppInstanceIdentifier:(UIDevice*)device
{
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    static NSString* UUID_KEY = @"CDVUUID";

    // Check user defaults first to maintain backwards compaitibility with previous versions
    // which didn't user identifierForVendor
    NSString* app_uuid = [userDefaults stringForKey:UUID_KEY];
    if (app_uuid == nil) {
        if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)]) {
            app_uuid = [[device identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
        } else {
            CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
            app_uuid = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
            CFRelease(uuid);
        }

        [userDefaults setObject:app_uuid forKey:UUID_KEY];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }

    return app_uuid;
}
```